# CSS wont display div background picture

Tags: css, image, html, background

It displays perfectly on my computer and it used to display normally online until I tried to replace that background picture, I don't know what happened, I've tried reverting back to old one now that one doesn't work either.

As I can see all other styles apply so do the pictures (which are all in the same folder - they load through css). So the CSS is okay, formatting is applied to text, divs, buttons and everything. The path should also be okay because background image is loading normally through the same code and is in the same folder.

This one loads perfectly :

```
html {
    background: url(images/background.png) repeat;
}
```

This one wont load no matter what :

```
#container {
    width: 588px;
    height: 617px;
    background-image:url(images/maintext60.png);
    margin: auto;    
}
```

Picture exists in that path I've checked a million times. I can access it through direct link in a browser. I've also tried

```
('images/maintext60.png');
(/images/maintext60.png);
(../images/maintext60.png);
```

And all other things I've found online. What happened? I didn't change anything except the picture name and now the first one which worked - doesn't! The Internet hates me.

Comment: Check the console to see if the request for the image succeeds.

Comment: Are you sure the image doesn't exist only on your local machine?

Comment: can you also try clearing your browser cache as well

Comment: @irrelephant I am sure because I can access it through direct link in a browser.

Comment: @dinukadev I've tried with all browsers and on my phone - same problem everywhere.

Comment: And you're not resetting #container later on in your css file by any chance?

Comment: @DanielFigueroa resetting it by reusing it below? No. Checked.

Comment: And you're sure that the other stylings that you've applied to #container works, I think I would change the background to a color just to see that #container in general works as it should.

Comment: @DanielFigueroa You're right, the color doesn't apply either. I have just tried it. I've tried it with `#container {
    width: 588px;
    height: 617px;
    background-color:#000;
    margin: auto;    
}` What now? id is correct and everything, I don't know why did it stop working...I wasn't changing anything but the image name.

Comment: So there you have it, it's not the background image it's the html-element. Check your html and make sure that the ID is correct.

Comment: @DanielFigueroa You should know that everything works on my computer(the image and the background color ive tried) but not online. The div is `<div id="container">`

Comment: I realize you've defined a height/width, but is it at all possible that it is collapsing due to floated or absolutely positioned child elements?  Without a demo of some sort, we can sit here guessing all night and not really get anywhere.

Comment: @user1880779 well then post the link or js-fiddle it.

Comment: @DanielFigueroa [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YKsay/)
Note - it kinda works here but not on my website ;\

Comment: on jfiddle i see the div with id "container" and the background color black. I don't see errors in the html and the css and the javascript is only related to the button. It just should work :) Do you have anything else that can interfere with it and that you didn't include in jsfiddle? @user1880779

Comment: @Fabio Nope, its just a simple site under construction so that is all. What can I do? The problem is that it worked in the beginning and then it stopped...I don't know what did I do. I'm telling you the internet hates me because it works everywhere(offline on computer and on jfiddle) except where it should work. I just pasted the code.

Comment: usually things happen according to rules and not casually :) but it doesn't work for you and it's strange..eheh..what can i say? Hmm have you tried to refresh your ftp? Have you tried to delete your cache and temporary files of the browser and tried to check the page again? The code seems alright so i'm starting to think about other issues..even if it remains strange. @user1880779

Comment: @Fabio it seems like the dark forces are against me, im telling you. help me brother and I will have you in my prayers.

Comment: hmm you uploaded it on the server and had the issue when you see it from there. Could you give me the link of the site under construction? I'd like to see it directly on your server as you do. @user1880779

Comment: @user1880779 Could you please provide a link to your site?

Comment: @Asad You can check the live non working demo [HERE](http://friendneed.com/drek/)

Comment: @Asad So..I set up a demo for you guys and you run away as soon as you see it :P

Comment: I checked and it seems the url of the image maintext60.png (http://friendneed.com/images/maintext60.png) gives a 404 error (not found). Did you upload it on the server? @user1880779

Comment: but in the link you gave me the container div is setup as this #container {
 width: 588px;
 height: 617px;
 background-image:url(/images/maintext60.png);
 margin: auto;
} @user1880779

Comment: @Fabio Yeah the Chrome says that I also checked. I uploaded the background color one, i re uploaded it and the chrome still says that. I have even tried downloading from the server to desktop and it said background-color (as i said) and not the image. Strange. Ill upload the image nevertheless.

Comment: @Fabio update [Direct Image Link](http://friendneed.com/images/maintext60.png)

Comment: now i see the background image in the page @user1880779

Comment: @Fabio Yeah me too after the update and clearing the cache..I think I'm having some kind of FTP issues. I tried to upload the new css background-color and it wont let me. I did overwrite it and it was the right file, i did refresh the FTP and it did upload it successfully but the chrome still said it was the old code. And when I downloaded it from the FTP it WAS the new file with background color. I'm confused.

Comment: yes i think a ftp or browser cache problem. @user1880779

Comment: You should accept the answer that was most correct.

Comment: @DanielFigueroa I will when I solve the problem, because I just found out that its not solved yet. That container css just wont apply settings even after hosting helped.

Comment: @user1880779 bummer, btw I think the hosting service you're using are giving you really bad service, I think this question should help as a reference for you to demand some free hosting or a refund. Because caching like that is certainly not very good. What if you had static webpages that you updated manually!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try to troubleshoot the problem with Chrome.

1. Open your site wherever it is (local or remote server) and open the Chrome Dev Tools (Cmd+ALt+I on OS-X, similar key combinations on Linux and Windows).
2. Go to the Elements Panel and look for the element with the `container` id.
3. Check the "Metrics" tab on the right side subpanel to see if it has the size you expected. If not, maybe the problem is not on the image file url.
4. If the `container` width and height are what you expected, check the "Styles" tab and look for the `background-image`property. If the image was not loaded properly, the property content will probably show where was the browser looking for your image.
5. You can also check the "Resources" Panel to see if the image was properly loaded.
6. Last thing I can think of: open the Network Panel and reload the page. You will have indications on every http request that your site is making, and the corresponding server responses.

Comment: Nice suggestions. The Metrics tab shows different size then it should be (in css rules) when I click on the container div. It says size is 1647x334. Also it says only : user agent stylesheetdiv {
display: block;
} under the "matched css rules" if that means anything to you.

Comment: I also used Chrome Dev Tools when i checked the page and i found no particular problems in the page hosted on jsfiddle. Anyway this is a good way to proceed. Try it also yourself. @user1880779

Comment: @Fabio Check the demo also here, it doesn't work here for example : 
[LIVE HOSTED DEMO](http://friendneed.com/drek/)

Comment: yes i checked. It seems the image resource can't load because it is not found on the server. Did you upload it? @user1880779

Comment: @Fabio The container div is currently set up as this : `#container { width: 588px; height: 617px; background-color:#000; margin: auto; }` so we don't have to search for images

Comment: carles, if it interests you check my answer i found what the problem was and thanks for your help i would never know without the suggestions you gave

Comment: @user1880779 I'm glad you got it solved and I'm also glad I was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For me it works if I change:

```
background-image:url(/images/maintext60.png);
```

to:

```
background-image:url(images/maintext60.png);
```

So doublecheck that that isn't the problem.

Comment: I've tried. Doesn't work. That's why I'm trying with background-color (so we don't have to waste time with images) now and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I understand that, but what I'm telling you is that i got it to work by just doing that little change. I think this has to do with cache more than problems in the code, except for the above mentioned problem obviously. How do you go about to clear the cache?

Comment: i found out the problem, you were right. if it interests you check my answer, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Before the image wasn't uploaded, in fact you see here:

[image: before]

But then i see it. Here it is the proof of what i see browsing the website:

[image: after]

Comment: you know whats funny? you should connect to my ftp and you would see that there is a new default.css file with background-color style but the chrome is still looking at the "old" one? Why is that?

Comment: it's incredible :P anyway sometimes i had problems with ftp too. But i don't think it's your fault. Try to refresh it, overwrite it.. @user1880779

Comment: yeah but now I can't change my css file at all (and that was the problem from beginning because I thought I was changing it but I wasn't), I can change it in ftp but browsers just keep using the first one I uploaded which doesn't exist on ftp anymore and i only have one current .css file. help?

Answer (score 1):

It was a caching problem, but not on my side. I was updating and trying to fix it while server was still looking at same old files. Here is the official response :

Hello,

We apologize for any inconvenience this has caused you. You are experiencing issue with CSS file is because of server setup. We do cache on our server. Varnish caching software is implemented to cache static pages for better performance. Now, I have updated the .htaccess file in your account to remove caching in your account. I have updated the following code in .htaccess file:

```
<Files *> 
Header set Cache-Control: "private, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0" 
Header set Expires: 0 
Header set Pragma: no-cache 
</Files>
```

Please check this by updating CSS files from your end.

Comment: yes i thought it could be a caching problem and i knew the server was Varnish because i checked the http fingerprint of the server but i didn't know it was a property set directly in the .htaccess file. Thanks for letting me know. I'm sorry you had troubles for some time. See, as i said it wasn't a problem of your code. At the end we learnt something new though. Let's look at the positive side :) @user1880779